# Angular 2 - Tracking animation of array by using binding

Tags: angular, animation, binding, ngfor

I would like to use an array for tracking the change ( to do animation step by step for each div)

When I hardcode 6 div, the animation worked well.

```
 <div [innerHTML]="broadcastInnerHtml[0]" style="background-color:azure; width: 23%; display: none; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;"
     [style.background-color]="colorBackground[0]"
     [@visibilityChanged]="visibility[0]">
    <p>Can you see me? 111111.</p>
</div>

<div [innerHTML]="broadcastInnerHtml[1]" style="background-color:azure; width: 23%; display: none; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;"
     [style.background-color]="colorBackground[1]"
     [@visibilityChanged]="visibility[1]">
    <p>Can you see me? 111111.</p>
</div>

<div [innerHTML]="broadcastInnerHtml[2]" style="background-color:azure; width: 23%; display: none; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;"
     [style.background-color]="colorBackground[2]"
     [@visibilityChanged]="visibility[2]">
    <p>Can you see me? 111111.</p>
</div>

<div [innerHTML]="broadcastInnerHtml[3]" style="background-color:azure; width: 23%; display: none; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;"
     [style.background-color]="colorBackground[3]"
     [@visibilityChanged]="visibility[3]">
    <p>Can you see me? 111111.</p>
</div>

<div [innerHTML]="broadcastInnerHtml[4]" style="background-color:azure; width: 23%; display: none; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;"
     [style.background-color]="colorBackground[4]"
     [@visibilityChanged]="visibility[4]">
    <p>Can you see me? 111111.</p>
</div>

<div [innerHTML]="broadcastInnerHtml[5]" style="background-color:azure; width: 23%; display: none; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;"
     [style.background-color]="colorBackground[5]"
     [@visibilityChanged]="visibility[5]">
    <p>Can you see me? 111111.</p>
</div>
```

But it's not a good way. I want to use Ngfor to generate div. So I change to

```
<div *ngFor="let visi of visibility; let idx=index"
    style="background-color:azure; width: 23%; display: none; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;" 
    [@visibilityChanged]="visi" 
    [innerHTML]="broadcastInnerHtml[idx]" 
    [style.background-color]="colorBackground[idx]">

        <p>Can you see me? 111111.</p>
</div>
```

After the change, the state work but animation. 
I have spent hours for it but still have no solution.
Please help. Thanks much

Comment: What happens when you use `visibility[idx]` instead of `visi` ? How did you guess that `[@visibilityChanged]='visi'` is causing the issue here ?

Comment: I tried visibility[idx] also and same, it didnt work. Sorry for the guess, I just suspect that is the cause. For not confusing everybody, I removed it already.

Comment: What version of angular 2 are you using ?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.0